# Why does my regex code not work?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I've been trying to customize my syntax highlighting patterns on TeXworks recently, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to deal with, for instance, content enclosed in `\footnote{}`. Sometimes I might have interlocked functions inside the footnote, so obviously the first closing bracket "stops" the highlighting pattern I try to define. 
After a bit of research I ended up finding this :

```
\\footnote\s*\{(?<=\{).*(?<=\})
```

I tested it [here](https://regex101.com/r/K4SQ5E/1) and it worked. However, when I try to implement it in TeXworks' `syntax-patterns.txt` file, it doesn't.

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem would be nice.

Comment: While a MWE in that sense might be a bit hard to do (it's not a problem in TeX code), "doesn't work" is a bit short. What do you see in TexWorks, or what error do you get? Keep in mind that there are several 'flavours' of regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every regex implementation is slightly different, particualrly once one goes outside of the core features. Your regex is using a positive look-behind (`(?<=`): that's not a totally 'standard' feature. The regex engine used by TeXworks is a pretty simple one: there are no look ahead/behind features. Indeed, the regex you've given is parsed as invalid by TeXworks: try using it in the search box. You simply can't use this approach here, sorry.